# Calculating Expected Loss in a Conditional that a Loss Event occur in a particular year.

Tags: probability, statistics, conditional-expectation

Regards, I found a question below and would like to test my view on this.

**Question :** The probability of a driver will not experience any loss event in one year ahead is $ 90 \%.$ In one year, it is known that the driver experience an event of loss of $X$ amount. The loss density function is below :
$$ f(x) = 2 e^{-2x}, \:\: 0 < x < \infty $$
What is the expected loss at that year?

**an Answer :**
I may see this as conditional expectation :
$$  E[X | L] = \int_{0}^{ \infty } x f_{X|L}(x) \: dx  $$
with $L$ is the event of experiencing any loss in that year. An argument would be that the conditional pdf is :
$$ f_{X|L}(x) = \frac{ f(x) }{ P(L) } = \frac{f(x)}{0.1} $$
$$  E[X | L] = \int_{0}^{ \infty } x f_{X|L}(x) \: dx = 10 \int_{0}^{\infty} 2x e^{-2x} dx = 5 $$

*But* the official answer to this particular question was set to $0.05$. May I have some inputs on this question, thanks. All the best.

Comment: The loss is $0$ with probability $90\%$. On the other $10\%$, the loss is exponential with parameter $2$, hence the mean loss is $0.5$. Thus the overall mean loss is $0\cdot90\%+0.5\cdot10\%=0.05$. (To reach a mean loss ten times higher than the highest possible mean loss should have rung a bell...)

Comment: @Did thanks for the answer, quite straightforward. I may say that the details in the question is ambiguous, which part would you think is incorrect in my answer?

Comment: "which part would you think is incorrect" First, your interpretation of $f(x)=2e^{-2x}$, which is already $f_{X\mid L}$, hence $E(X\mid L)=.5$. Second, that you are missing that one does not ask for $E(X\mid L)$ but for $$E(X)=E(X\mid L)P(L)+E(X\mid L^c)P(L^c)=E(X\mid L)\cdot.1$$

Comment: @Did , by notation : $E(X)$ is $ \int x f(x) dx$. But this is true if we see it as $f_{X}(x) = f(x)$, which I just noticed that it is not. So the term $f(x)$ may obscure a little.

Comment: Yeah, only replace "may obscure a little" by "is quite wrong".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $X$ be the loss (amount), $X\sim \mathcal{E}xp(2)$ and $L$ a Bernoulli random variable with $p=0.1$, thus the expected loss can be calculated by the total expectation formula 
$$
E[X] = E[E[X|L]] = 0\times0.9 + 0.1\times E[X|L] = 0.1E[X] = 0.1\times\frac{1}{2} = 0.05. 
$$

Answer (score 1):

Formally, if $X$ is the severity variable and $N$ the frequency variable, then $$X \mid N = 1 \sim \operatorname{Exponential}(\lambda = 2), \\ N \sim \operatorname{Bernoulli}(p = 0.1).$$  It follows from the law of total probability that $$\operatorname{E}[X] = \operatorname{E}[X \mid N = 1]\Pr[N = 1] + \operatorname{E}[X \mid N = 0]\Pr[N = 0] = \operatorname{E}[X \mid N = 1](0.1) + 0(0.9).$$  Since $$\operatorname{E}[X \mid N = 1] = \frac{1}{\lambda} = \frac{1}{2},$$ the result follows.

Note that the unconditional (marginal) distribution of $X$ is "mixed" in the sense that it contains a discrete part and a continuous part.  Thus the CDF is discontinuous:  $$F_X(x) = \Pr[X \le x] = \begin{cases} 0, & x < 0 \\ 1 - \tfrac{1}{10} e^{-2x}, & x \ge 0. \end{cases}$$  This is because when $x \ge 0$, we have $$\Pr[X \le x] = \Pr[X \le x \mid N = 0]\Pr[N = 0] + \Pr[X \le x \mid N = 1]\Pr[N = 1] \\
= (1)(0.9) + (1 - e^{-2x})(0.1) \\
= 1 - \tfrac{1}{10}e^{-2x}.$$